# React native refresh token mechanism

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, refresh-token

I am struggling to find out the issue with my refresh token mechanism. What happens is this

1. Users logs into my application and receives the token
2. Token is saved into local storage (user also gets refresh token)
3. For each request I have an axios interceptor for response where I check that the token is expired or not. If yes, I call backend to get refresh token and save it in the app and call the other waiting api's.

This is how it works in most of the cases, but sometimes there is a mismatch. What happens is that my client called the refresh token, the backend does it jobs and creates a new r-token and save it in database but the app still has the old token.

So on the next request it gets 400 where it sends the request with old token. One scenario that I found out was that if the user closes the app before it gets the response this error will come. Any way to cater that?

Here is my code.

```
api.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // If the request succeeds, we don't have to do anything and just return the response
    return response
  },
  function (error) {
    const errorResponse = error.response
    if (isTokenExpiredError(errorResponse)) {
      return resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error)
    }
    var isError = store.getState().appState.GeneralError
    if (!isError) {
      var obj = {
        error: true,
        status: errorResponse.status,
      }
      store.dispatch(generalError(obj))
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
  },
)
function isTokenExpiredError(errorResponse) {
  return errorResponse.status === 401
}


let isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false

let subscribers = []

async function resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error) {
  try {
    const { response: errorResponse } = error
    const resetToken = await TokenStorage.getToken() // Your own mechanism to get the refresh token to refresh the JWT token
    if (!resetToken) {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
   
    /* Proceed to the token refresh procedure
    We create a new Promise that will retry the request,
    clone all the request configuration from the failed
    request in the error object. */
    const retryOriginalRequest = new Promise(resolve => {
      /* We need to add the request retry to the queue
    since there another request that already attempt to
    refresh the token */
      addSubscriber(accesstoken => {
        errorResponse.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accesstoken
        resolve(axios(errorResponse.config))
      })
    })
    if (!isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken) {
      isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = true
      const refreshToken = await TokenStorage.getRefreshToken()
      const userName = await TokenStorage.getUsername()
      const response = await AuthenticationService.refreshToken(
        refreshToken,
        userName,
      )

      if (!response) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
      TokenStorage.storeTokenInfo(
        response.access_token,
        response.refresh_token,
        response.userName,
      ) // save the newly refreshed token for other requests to use

      const newToken = response.access_token
      isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
      onAccessTokenFetched(newToken)
    }
    return retryOriginalRequest
  } catch (err) {
    isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
    store.dispatch(signOut({ relogin: true, notServerLogout: true }))
    return Promise.reject(err)
  }
}

function onAccessTokenFetched(accesstoken) {
  // When the refresh is successful, we start retrying the requests one by one and empty the queue
  subscribers.forEach(callback => callback(accesstoken))
  subscribers = []
}

function addSubscriber(callback) {
  subscribers.push(callback)
}
```

And here is the code for refresh token api call

```
async refreshToken(refreshToken: string, username: string) {
    try {
      let data = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refreshToken

      data = data + '&client_id=' + Config.CLIENT_ID
      data = data + '&username=' + username
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        accept: 'application/json',
      }


      return api
        .post(Config.API_BASE_URI + '/token', data, { headers })
        .then(function (response: any) {
          LogService.logError(
            'apiClient',
            'apptype',
            `Response fra refresh token call ${JSON.stringify(response)}`,
          )

          return response.data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          throw `Failed to refresh token just in the catch block inside the axios request - ${JSON.stringify(
            error,
          )}`
        })
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Failed to refresh token outside throw' + JSON.stringify(e)
    }
  },
```

Its a long shot but looking forward for some help.

Comment: Based on the first snipped, I understood that you check if the token is still valid based on the API response, right? Meaning that, until one request fails with that specific error, you'll be using the respective token

Comment: I didn't understood that. My logic, what I think how it works is, that as soon as an api returns 401 so the app calls refresh token api while all the other api's wait for the refresh token call if that is in progress.